# What are the 'implications for diagnostics of the standard linear regression assumptions' of the results $\sum_{i}e_{i}=0$ and $\sum_{i}e_{i}x_{i}=0$?

Tags: regression

I've been doing some work where I had to prove, for standard linear regression, the results $\sum_{i}e_{i}=0$ and $\sum_{i}e_{i}x_{i}=0$. I did not find this to be a problem, but I have also been asked to state the "implications for diagnostics of the standard linear regression assumptions" for these results and this is just a jumble of words to me.

Could someone perhaps rephrase this and put me on the right path to work out what I am being asked? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: did you need to use any of the assumptions in the answer below to find the result, or was it just pure algebra? If it is the latter, and thus holding true without reference to any assumptions about an underlying population, these equalities can't tell you much.

Comment: I think the question is assuming the reader understands the sample is a proxy for the underlying population and therefore the sample can be used to gain insight about the population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what are the standard regression assumptions (generally 4)?

1) Mean of the error term $= 0$

2) variance of error is constant for all settings of $X$

3) Errors are independent of one another

4) Errors are normally distributed

$E \sim \text{i.i.d } N(0, \sigma^2)$ is another way to see that.

Now, with this and your proofs of those equalities, what ways do you think you can test the above regression assumptions/ how can you tell if they are reasonably satisfied or perhaps violated too severely?

This is my interpretation of their question.